# MDX name set not working in calculated member

Tags: ssas, mdx, sql-server-data-tools

I have a named set like this :

```
(   
        [DimDate].[Hierarchy].currentmember.lag(1)
        ,
        [Measures].[Fact Transaction Count]
)
```

This code give me count of transaction of yesterday current member. now I want to use it to calculate daily growth. some thing like this :

```
    (
           ([Measures].[Fact Transaction Count] - GetPreviousTransactionValueDate.Item(0).Item(0)) / GetPreviousTransactionValueDate.Item(0).Item(0)
     ) * 100
```

when use it in SSMS I can get output but when I send it to SSDT I get a Null value for all hierarchy.

this code give me output :

```
 with member measures.GetPreviousTransactionValueDate as 
 (
        [DimDate].[Hierarchy].currentmember.lag(1)
        ,
        [Measures].[Fact Transaction Count]
 )
 member measures.Roshd as 
 (
   ([Measures].[Fact Transaction Count] - measures.GetPreviousTransactionValueDate) / measures.GetPreviousTransactionValueDate) * 100
 )
 select non empty( measures.Roshd)  on columns,
 non empty([DimDate].[Hierarchy].[Month]) on rows
 from [Cube]
```

I want to only use named Set not another calculated member for this topic. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that my way is wrong. because sets works on dimensions not use for creating a calculated member.